# Algorithm for exhaustive incremental distribution into a fixed number of slots

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, pseudocode

I have a simulation that I'm building and I'm in need of an algorithm to distribute/redistribute a fixed total floating point value into 10 different "slots" by set increments and repeat the process until all permutations have been simulated. I know I have to set a bound because I am working with floating point values.

In the simplest case, I'd have my 10 slots and a total value of 10.0 to distribute, with the smallest increment being 1.0, so I'm working purely with integers. So I'd like to be able to run the simulation from this point:

```
| 10 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |
```

To this point:

```
|  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 10 |
```

With ever possible permutation that sums to 10.0 in between.

I know I can do the math to calculate the number of permutations, I'm just not sure how to devise an algorithm to achieve this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking for the number of "permutations" or the "permutations" themselves ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: the permutations themselves, since I'm running a simulator that requires the data. As stated in the question, I know how to calculate the number of permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what your language of choice is, but here is a solution in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    slots(4, 0, new int[3]);
}

private static void slots(int sum, int index, int[] array) {
    if (index == array.length - 1) {
        array[index] = sum;
        // Do something with the array here.
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i <= sum; i++) {
            array[index] = i;
            slots(sum - i, index + 1, array);
        }
    }
}
```

When I replace the comment by `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` the output is

```
[0, 0, 4]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 2]
[0, 3, 1]
[0, 4, 0]
[1, 0, 3]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 0]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 0]
[3, 0, 1]
[3, 1, 0]
[4, 0, 0]
```

Comment: That's perfect! Nice and concise too. Extra points for answering within an hour

Comment: Thanks. I like this kind of question.